# URI segment as parameter to function: passing commas,+,date formats as URI segments allowed?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

Can you pass commas or + symbols or data in date - time format as parameters in URI segment in codeigniter?
like calling through ajax a url like : controller/function/argument1/argument2

Now can this argument 1 contain characters like +,(,),comma when called from front end? Seems otherwise.I tried passing an address variable to the function through the URI segment, however the + signs, commas present in the address generate an error. The same happened with date format that is passed from frontend. Is this a restriction or is there a work-around?

Comment: I have realised that changing the characters in the config file in codeigniter lets you accept these characters as URI segments but the config file also states that- DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!! Can someone shed light on the REPERCUSSION? Is it serious security issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the `config.php` file in your `application/config` folder you can find the following:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify with a regular expression which characters are permitted
| within your URLs.  When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed
| characters they will get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

So, basically, you can change it to accept whatever symbol you want,
but I really don't know what type of reason that lets you pass other than the above allowed symbols in your uri.

Comment: thanks mamdouh, i'm trying the fields to accept address an ddate from front end. So address may have several characters besides the default allowed ones, also the date-time format returned from frontend has parentheses and '+' and ':' sign. Im trying to send the same to backend through the uri segments. While I could add to allow more characters but as indicated in the config file, I dont understand the REPERCUSSIONS. U wud have any idea about it?

Comment: you can send your data via `post` which will reduce the risk a bit, and you can use `data('Y-m-d',$user_side_date);` to reformat your userside date to adjust with mysql format, take a look at [date class from php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for more info

Comment: the date format is still a problem, although otherwise changes in config file make it work.

Comment: @yash - I still recommend you to use post calling method, and that's when you can use the date format, I didn't say you can use it with uri string.